# Why does a Google Play Pre-launch report show network activity when testing an app that doesn't use the network?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Consider an Android app that does no network I/O: It links to no HTTP libraries or any third party libraries at all, does not request `INTERNET` or `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission in the manifest, and uses no advertising software.

Yet after uploading an App Bundle to the Google Play Developer's Console, the Pre-launch report's Performance section reports on network bytes sent and received from one or two of the test devices!

[image: Pre-launch report > Performance, showing network I/O]

The detail report for this App Bundle shows just one spike of network activity at 4:05 into the test run, where it claims to send 400B and receive 818 bytes. The recorded screenshot video shows nothing changing on screen at that time.

The app has an `TextInputEditText` field, so one hypothesis was that this field was accessing a spell-check server, but the field gets accessed earlier in the test run, not at 4:05, and it has spell-checking disabled.

- What code in the test device could be doing network I/O, in this case on Samsung Galaxy S9 and not on the other test devices? (With an earlier App Bundle version, both Samsung Galaxy S9 and Xiaomi Redmi 6A did some network I/O.)
- Is this happening from Samsung extensions to the Android OS?
- Is this just irrelevant network I/O from an independent process such as the test lab communication?
- Any other hypotheses?

Comment: If the app doesn't have internet permission, it's not sending data.  TextInputEditText doesn't reach out to a spell check server, spell check is done on device-  server latency would be unusably high for spell check, you want to do that per key which means under a second.  Given the extremely small amount and that you see it on only one device, I'd suspect it's the device misattributing it.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, I was hypothesizing about fetching the spell-check dictionary for the current locale. Anyway, another Pre-launch report has "samsung Galaxy S9" with some slow frames and a `RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.facebook.katana.FacebookAccountReceiver` which is *not* from my app. The test lab ought to disable FB and ignore exceptions from other apps.